# Configuring default output for Aptitude package search

Tags: apt, configuration, search, aptitude

In most flavors of Linux that I've used, the output for apt search does not include the *current state* display but in Linux Mint (Sylvia) it is displaying and I would like to remove it because it interferes with my string-beginning (^) grep filters.

When I use the formatting flag (-F) I can get it to work just fine.

```
apt search -F "%p" apache
```

I would prefer this to be the default behavior.  I have tried adding the configuration to the **.aptitude/config** file but am seeing no change.  I tried both with Aptitude capitalized and all lowercase, as the configurations in the file by default have it lowercase, but the documentation has it capitalized.

```
Aptitude::UI::Package-Display-Format "%p";
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but when I add the display format to **.aptitude/config** it's inserting the following line above it every time, and if I delete the line it is replaced the next time I open the file.

```
aptitude::UI "";
```

I'm using apt 1.2.27 and aptitude 0.7.4-2ubuntu2.

**Aptitude references**
https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s05s05.en.html#configPackage-Display-Format
https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s05s01.en.html